# Android compare booleans

Tags: java, android, boolean

I am making a simple app where you have to toggle buttons/booleans trying to guess the correct combination. I was wondering the simplest way to compare the toggles booleans against the "right" combination. For example if user has:

> boolean 1: true
>   boolean 2: false
>   Boolean 3: true

but the correct combination is:

> boolean 1: true
>   boolean 2: true
>   Boolean 3: true

I want the user to see a message that says you have 2 out of 3 correct. I have

```
public void go(View view){
    if (bool1 == true && boo12 == true && bool3 == true) {
        // do this
    } else {
        // display the correct amount of booleans the user has correct.
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really simplify it by
if(bool1 && bool2 && bool3) much easier on the eyes

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) for the correct combination (set the bits that correspond to "true", clear the bits that correspond to "false").
2. When you want to check the user's input, create a `BitSet` from the buttons that are pressed (set "true", clear "false").
3. Correctness can be checked with `correctValue.equals(usersAttempt)`.
4. A count can be obtained by doing `usersAttempt.xor(correctValue)` then `usersAttempt.cardinality()` will return the number of *incorrect* values.

This requires a bare minimal amount of coding. For your example:

```
// Correct: [true,true,true]
BitSet correct = new BitSet(3);
correct.set(0); // <= true
correct.set(1); // <= true
correct.set(2); // <= true

// User's attempt (buttonN.isChecked() is just placeholder, drop in whatever
// code you actually use to get the state of your buttons):
BitSet attempt = new BitSet(3); 
attempt.set(0, button0.isChecked()); // <= true in your example
attempt.set(1, button1.isChecked()); // <= false in your example
attempt.set(2, button2.isChecked()); // <= true in your example

// Check answer (produces false in your example):
boolean matchIsPerfect = attempt.equals(correct);

// Get the count (produces 1 in your example): 
attempt.xor(correct);
int incorrectCount = attempt.cardinality();

// To get the correct count just subtract 'incorrectCount' from total.

// Another way to check if attempt is correct is 'if (incorrectCount == 0)'.

// Note that the remaining bits set in 'attempt' after the above xor()
// will correspond to the individual inputs that weren't correct.
```

This will let you support any size, the code is clear and you don't need to do any of the logic on your own. Note that you can simplify the button -> user's attempt setup if you have an array of buttons or can access user input given an index.

Comment: What if the correct set included 9 booleans with 2 being false?

Comment: @user2941841 Read the linked documentation for `BitSet`. You can use `set(int,boolean)` to set or clear individual items (there is also plain old `clear(index)` which is the same as `set(index, false)`). You can manipulate the bits in any way you see fit (see how we're doing it for the user's attempt in the above example?)

Comment: I'll check it out.im confused how in your example the attempt  sets all bits when one is incorrect.

Comment: @user2941841 You didn't show the code for your buttons, so I just assumed `buttonN.isChecked()` returns `true` if `buttonN` is checked and `false` if not. I made those up. So in your example (where user has input *[true,false,true]*), I'd imagine `button1.isChecked()` would return `false` and the other two would return `true`. It's just an illustrative placeholder for your actual user input code; substitute in whatever code you use to get the toggle state of your buttons from the user. Or just play with `BitSet` on your own until you understand it, then you'll see how to use it as a tool. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the conditions are not always to be true, say bool3 needs to be false, you can use something like this maybe. Otherwise, as the other answers mentioned, an array would work best probably.

```
int correctCount = 0;

if (bool1) correctCount++;
if (bool2) correctCount++;
if (!bool3) correctCount++;

if (correctCount == 3) {
    // do this
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(correctCount) + " out of 3 correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Some actually will be false. This may be the answer. I will test it out and report back

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your "right" combination will include both `true` and `false` values, the following method will return the number of matches, or `-1` if the array lengths don't match:

```
private int getMatches(boolean[] toggleValues, boolean[] matchPattern)
{
    if(toggleValues.length != matchPattern.length)
        return -1;

    int matches = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < toggleValues.length; j++)
    {
        if(toggleValues[j] == matchPattern[j])
        {
            matches++;
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

As an example, if you have 3 `ToggleButton`s, `tb1`, `tb2`, and `tb3`, the following will return 2:

```
tb1.setChecked(true);
tb2.setChecked(false);
tb3.setChecked(false);

final boolean[] matchPattern = {true, false, true};
final boolean[] toggleValues = {tb1.isChecked(), tb2.isChecked(), tb3.isChecked()};

int matches = getMatches(toggleValues, matchPattern);
```

This method will allow you to easily change the matching pattern without changing code, e.g by reading stored values into the `matchPattern` array from a file or `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: +1, I think this is the right and most elegant answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it, as the number of boolean values can be more than 3. you may want to use for loop (easy way) and iterate it for the end of the value and return the number of counts to the value k. here k-> number of true boolean values and b is an array containing the array of boolean values.

```
public void go(View view){

      boolean b[]={bool1,bool2,bool3,bool4,bool5,bool6,bool7,bool8,bool9,bool10};

     int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    {
        if(b[i]==true)
        {

            k++;
        }


    }

   if(k==b.length)
       {
           do task
       }
    else 
       {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), k+ "out of "+b.length+ "correct",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }



}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I will be dealing with at least 9 booleans so that method would be extreme cumbersome.

Comment: i have edited it, it can be used for any number of boolean operation

Comment: Did you try this code , it will be working for more than 3 also.